# Error decode byte when send image in discord

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord.py, bytesio

I have some problems with sending images in discord. I decide to use **Pillow** library for creating images and I want to send image which is created by this library **without save**. I found out what I can convert Image object to binary data and put in fp argument. But it raised encoding error.

**Code:**

```
image = Image.open("test.png")

image_binary = BytesIO()
image.save(image_binary, "PNG")
image_binary = image_binary.getvalue()

await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary))
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Python\phoenix\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\Python\phoenix\modules\welcome.py", line 25, in test_image
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary))
  File "D:\Projects\Python\phoenix\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\file.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: I don't know `discord` at all, but the `image_binary` parameter you are passing to it on the last line of your code is not a filepointer - it is a buffer containing the entire contents (already read) from a PNG image file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So should I write in filename argument any name? Here is documentation about `discord.File` - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File

Comment: No, it's precisely NOT a file You need to pass a **buffer** not a fils to `ctx.send()` but I don't know where that is documented either, and you have removed the `import` statements so I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: But I should send a file in the chat, aren't I? Function `send` don't support buffer and that is need to convert file object. Otherwise never mind I found solution. Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
image = Image.open("test.png")

with BytesIO() as image_binary:
    image.save(image_binary, "PNG")
    image_binary.seek(0)
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary,filename="image.png"))
```

Comment: please avoid answering with code only answers. Answers with explaining text are more helpful for future readers and more likely to be upvoted

Comment: I am guessing that the Seek is required to move a pointer back to the beginning of the stream.  Without the filename parameter, it is sent to Discord but Discord does not know how to process it.  The filename doesn't need to be referenced anywhere else, but you need it with a graphical extension (PNG for example) so it knows it is image data that can be displayed inline.