# UnicodeDecodeError for PIL.Image.fromarray

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to pass a PIL Image to a function as `io.BytesIO()` to avoid saving it on the hard drive. The image is the result of multiple PIL Images pasted together horizontally and it is created with `Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))`. When the pasting is done, I create a byte array and save the image in it:

```
imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
pasted_img.save(imgByteArr, format='PNG')

return imgByteArr.getvalue()
```

The result has to be loaded in a [discord.File](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.File) object, though this errors show up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/DiscordBot/scripts/uno/uno_client.py", line 167, in test
    f = discord.File(new_im)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\file.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.fp = open(fp, 'rb')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Programmazione/DiscordBot/scripts/uno/uno_client.py", line 67, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python-latest\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

### EDIT

I'll mention that I need to send this image via Discord message. This is what I use to load the image and send it:

```
new_im = join_imgs(imgs)  # the above-mentioned function
f = discord.File(new_im)
await channel.send('Test', file=f)
```

Comment: I can't see the line that actually caused the error - how did you try to load it? The `89` is exactly correct as the first byte of a PNG file. Maybe you need to pass the entire BytesIO object, i.e. `imgByteArr` to discord, rather than just the contents of the buffer?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I also tried to return the byte array: the file is loaded without errors but once the discord message is sent, the file content is 0kb.

Comment: How did you try to load it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell just as in my question, but omitting the ```getvalue()``` from ```return imgByteArr```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see the line that loads the image into discord. I can see the line that saves a PIL Image into a BytesIO.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't think it was necessary, but I'll edit the question

Comment: Ok, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58676192/2836621

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.